# How to Edit table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ipad

My table view contains detail disclosure button and disclosure indicator buttons. i want to delete some rows according to my necessity. So, i am using the tableView editing delegate
and setting its property to Yes.
self.tableView.editing = YES;

When the above statement is added to my code detail disclosure button are not visible.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the cells' accessory views to be visible during editing, set your cells' `editingAccessoryType` or `editingAccessoryView` properties accordingly in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.